# I have generated cookies file for Chrome Extension I need to load it in HashMap<String,String> in Java

Tags: java, cookies, hashmap, jsoup

I have cookies txt file with generated data from Chrome extension is look like this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

.site.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1701453620  _ga GA1.2.10834324067.1638446981
.site.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1638123020  _gid    GA1.2.25433025264.1638446981
.site.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1646432624  _fbp    fb.1.1643546988197.973328968
```

I need to load it to hashmap and to use it in Jsoup connection

```
 HashMap<String,String> coockies = load.file

 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(mainUrl).cookies(cookies).get();
```

It is possible to load the txt file and to convert it to hashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first pre-process the text file to get a key-value list. Something like this:

```sh
grep "^[^#]" cookies.txt | awk '{print $6 " " $7}'
```

```
_ga GA1.2.10834324067.1638446981
_gid GA1.2.25433025264.1638446981
_fbp fb.1.1643546988197.973328968
```

The code above strips off lines beginning with a `#` and empty lines. Next, the result is filtered to only select the 6th (cookie name) and 7th (cookie value) column.

If you save the output of the above bash command into `filtered.txt`, you can parse cookie information in Java like so:

```java
Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("filtered.txt"))) {
    stream.forEach(line -> {
        String[] columns = line.split(" ");
        cookies.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
    });
}
```

We are simply grabbing the *key* and *value* from every row to fill our `cookies` map; I suppose the code could be shorter, however, at the expense of readability.

---

#### References

- [How to grep lines which does not begin with "#" or ";"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60994/269048)
- [cut column 2 from text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285774/269048)
- [How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868369/6367213)

Comment: Thank you for answer I see the jsoup cookies are different format I think from this I have in the file but will test tomorrow may be working